# windows native functions in ntdll.dll in user mode moved to kernel mode

Tags: windows, reverse-engineering, ntdll

I was looking in my spartime at the ntdll.dll with IDA.

I used to use NtAccessCheckAndAuditAlarm/NtDisplayString to code egghunters in order to parse memory and check if i can read memory or not of a PE.

But it works in older version of windows, not anymore on win 10.

At this time, i use a Win 10 and i figured out that the NtAccessCheckAndAuditAlarm and NtDisplayString don't exist anymore, but are replaced with ZwAccessCheckAndAuditAlarm and ZwDisplayString (which are kernel functions)

So i was wondering when the change take place.

And so, if there are other functions in user mode to replace those 2, because i don't want to write kernel code.

Thanks

Comment: your question is unclear

Comment: Ok, i will modify my post to make it clearer

Comment: *At this time, i use a Win 10 and i figured out that the NtAccessCheckAndAuditAlarm and NtDisplayString don't exist anymore, but are replaced with ZwAccessCheckAndAuditAlarm and ZwDisplayString (which are kernel functions)* - ??? all this is wrong

Comment: Ok thank you for this relevant comment ^^ and teach me something.

But indeed, i read wrong the documentation : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/kernel/using-nt-and-zw-versions-of-the-native-system-services-routines

So i guess i answered myself to my question.

Comment: in user mode no difference between Zw and Nt functions. this 2 names point to the same. and then unclear what you try todo